# WPF font resouce not working, possible issue with font name

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

I am trying to use a font called `Suisse Int'l Cond` which is located in my project as `fonts/SuisseIntlCond-Regular.otf` and a build action of *Resource*

[image]

Other examples of OTF font in the project work without issue.

Works:

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="fonts/moon.otf #moon"/>
```

Dosn't Work:

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="fonts/SuisseIntlCond-Regular.otf #Suisse Int'l Cond"/>
```

My guess is it might be an issue with the `'` char in the name or something wrong with the font itself but I have been unable to confirm either of these as the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Importing and then exporting the font using Glyphr Studio resolves the issue even with keeping the same name.

[How do I change a font's metadata (specifically a title)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930217/how-do-i-change-a-fonts-metadata-specifically-a-title)